# Vue, separate component fires off 'not a function' message

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Everything here displays and acts how i want except for my call to the `setInputName` function. I believe the reason for this is because that happens within the `tabs` component which is built on a separate component and template, which then uses another component/template `tab` for the individual list item tabs.

The problem here is that when I click my list items, the console prints that `_vm.setInputName is not a function`

How can I fix this to be able to call this function from within the rendered template?

```
    <tabs>
      <tab name="Activity" :selected="true">
        <div class="row notesInput" id="notesInput">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="tabs">
              <ul style="border-bottom:none !important; text-decoration:none">
                <li v-on:click="setInputName('public')">Public</li>
                <li v-on:click="setInputName('public')">Internal</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" v-bind:name="inputName">
              <br>
              Input name is: {{ inputName }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </tab>
    </tabs>

    <script>
    Vue.component('tabs', {
      template: `
            <div>
                <div class="tabs">
                  <ul>
                    <li v-for="tab in tabs" :class="{ 'is-active': tab.isActive }">
                        <a :href="tab.href" @click="selectTab(tab)">{{ tab.name }}</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tabs-details">
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        `,

      data() {
        return { 
          tabs: [],
         };
      },

      created() {

        this.tabs = this.$children;

      },
      methods: {

        selectTab(selectedTab) {
          this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
            tab.isActive = tab.name == selectedTab.name;
          });
        } } });

    Vue.component('tab', {

      template: `

            <div v-show="isActive"><slot></slot></div>

        `,

      props: {
        name: { required: true },
        selected: { default: false } },


      data() {

        return {
          isActive: false,
        };


      },

      computed: {

        href() {
          return '#' + this.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
      } },

      mounted() {

        this.isActive = this.selected;

      } });


    export default {
      components: {
        Multipane,
        MultipaneResizer,
      },
      data () {
            return {
                inputName: '',
            }
      },
      computed: {

      },
      methods: {

      setInputName(str) {
        this.inputName = str;
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: You have many Vue.Component. Your `setInputName` function should be in the first Vue.component I guess.

Comment: 1) It's bad practice to put two components in one file,  2) It's non-standard to use `Vue.component` in a single file component.  Ideally, you have 1:1 SFCs and they use the `export default` object block to do their setup.  3) There is a missing `}` in your example where `methods` would be closed.

Comment: I put your code in a JSFiddle: and it works https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/3u7b81aq/2/

Comment: @Terry the jsfiddle doesn't have the 'export default' block though, that's what seems to be causing the issue

Comment: @Dan I implemented all of those things and have now cleared the errors, thank you! upon clicking, it puts 'public' into the inputName element now but it doesn't toggle after that so I'll need to look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is because you are calling the function from another component.
but your function is in another function. If you want this to work then you should extend your component in which your function exists and then you can use it.